# Grub bootloader broke after Windows 10 install on dual boot (2 drive) ZBook

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

My Linux drive will no longer boot.
I have a dual boot ZBook. RHEL 7.9 workstation and Windows 10 Pro. Windows crashed and I reinstalled it. I removed the linux drive before I installed Win10? My grub bootloader is now broken. How do I recover linux grub bootloader without loosing all my data on the linux drive since I cannot boot to my linux drive?

I am only familiar with Linux and Windows, I am by no means an expert, so I need help please. I'm really good at following directions and looking stuff up for fixing these type issues when they pop up. But I have not been able to find a fix for my situation.

Comment: Boot from LiveUSB and run the GRUB install - it should detect two drives with different OSes and install just fine.

Comment: Thank you White Owl for responding so quick. Would Ubuntu live disc be the same thing (I assume so)? I have that. So I will give that a try.

Comment: Yes, RHELbaby, Ubuntu live disc should be the same as LiveUSB. You can also use something called boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . The goal is for the grub to run os-probe and find/configure the OSes

Comment: When a drive is unplugged, UEFI forgets boot entry. For whatever reason if Windows it usually finds entry again. Reinstall of grub is probably easiest, but you can use efibootmgr to add new entry. see `man efibootmgr`

Comment: I am running in legacy mode - no UEFI. What about running rescue mode at boot up from install dvd?

Comment: OK, got it fixed. My DA mistake. Somehow I mixed drives and put in the wrong drive after I installed Windows. So of course the bootloader won't work.

Thank you White Owl, Mikalaj Bucwald, and oldfred for jumping in there. Very much appreciated.

After I put the correct drive in there I ran:

grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

to create a new bootloader and all is well with my little world again.